# Using minibuffer while the cursor is on a org-ref citation link

Tags: minibuffer, org-link, org-ref

When I run `(y-or-n-p "Prompt")` while the cursor is on an org-ref citation link, the prompt appears for a second and then disappears again to continue displaying the information about the article corresponding to the link. How do I avoid this? That is, how can I temporarily disable the showing of information about the article in the minibuffer?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

from the [org-ref manual](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/master/org-ref.org):

## Controlling link messages and tooltips

Org-ref is setup to provide messages in the minibuffer when your cursor is on a link, and tooltips when your mouse hovers over a link. If this is distracting you can turn it off by putting this in your init file:

```
(setq org-ref-show-citation-on-enter nil)
```

Alternatively, you can turn this on and off interactively with the commands:

```
org-ref-mouse-messages-on
org-ref-mouse-messages-off
```

Comment: Setting `org-ref-show-citation-on-enter` did not do the job. However, when searching for the uses of this variable, I discovered the actual functions intended for this purpose (see my reply).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer of @Tyler, I discovered two functions: `org-ref-cancel-link-messages` and `org-ref-show-link-messages`, which do the job.